# How to get Client IP in Lua Sockets

Tags: networking, network-programming, lua, client-server, luasocket

I'm having trouble locating how I go about getting the ip address of each client as they connect to my server, using LuaSockets; 
Also: I apologise if this has been answered in another post, but I could find it; Link me if this is the case.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getpeername](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/tcp.html#getpeername) should work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `conn:getpeername()`, it returns host and port of the client.